# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) wp-load.php on line 1

Tags: php, wordpress, http

Hi I have this error displaying, But There is no if in the file wp-load.php line 1

also when I replace the wp-load.php with original one

```
<?php @include'wp-admin/includes/static-template.php';?>
```

```
/** Define ABSPATH as this file's directory */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
define( 'ABSPATH', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' );

}

error_reporting( E_CORE_ERROR | E_CORE_WARNING | E_COMPILE_ERROR |E_ERROR   | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_USER_ERROR | E_USER_WARNING | E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR );
```

first linke which includes static template is added every time.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a space between `include` and the `file-name`

Change

```
<?php @include'wp-admin/includes/static-template.php';?>
```

To

```
<?php @include 'wp-admin/includes/static-template.php'; ?>
```

Best way to do it:

```
<?php @include('wp-admin/includes/static-template.php'); ?>
```

Comment: What are you saying is not clear at all. I don't see any missing semi-colons on the question.

Comment: After IF


`if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
define( 'ABSPATH', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' );

};

error_reporting( E_CORE_ERROR | E_CORE_WARNING | E_COMPILE_ERROR |E_ERROR   | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_USER_ERROR | E_USER_WARNING | E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR );
`

Comment: You should be clear when you write an answer. And if you are saying to add semi-colon after the if-block, then you should know semi-colons are not necessary after curly-braces. And the error says unexpected `if`, it does not say unexpected `error_reporting`.

Comment: This is totally wrong  `<?php @include'wp-admin/includes/static-template.php';?>`  Should be  `<?php include('wp-admin/includes/static-template.php'); ?>`

Comment: Use the edit link on your answer to correct it and provide an improved answer with useful description. See [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some guidelines if you need.